# Android Studio Chat Feature

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have implemented a simple chat feature in android studio and used Firebase Realtime database to save the chat. Everything works fine but when the message goes over a certain amount of letter count, the new text goes above instead of under the old messages.

```
// General Chat
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ChatBox");

        database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                String[] message = snapshot.getValue().toString().split(",");

                // Cleaning the Text Area
                chatBox.setText("");

                for(int i=0; i < message.length; i++){
                    String[] finalMessage = message[i].split("=");
                    chatBox.append(finalMessage[1] + "\n");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                chatBox.setText("Error!");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of extracting the data from Firebase by parsing the string, I recommend using the built-in operations of the `DataSnapshot` class to get the data.

Something like this:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ChatBox");

database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        chatBox.setText("");
        for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            chatBox.append(messageSnapshot.getValue(String.class) + "\n");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        chatBox.setText("Error: "+error.toString());
    }
});
```